# Windows batch start chrome process with defined process ID

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, process, kill

I have to start a Web Application with a batch file in the Chrome Browser with a predefined process ID so i can kill that specific Chrome Window later with another batch file. Is there any way to to this?

Comment: No it's not possible. It's the wrong workflow. You should start the browser and store the process id or you simply kill later the process by its name

Answer (score 1):

By typing this command on the CMD console you can see how to create a process :

```
wmic process call create /?
```

---

And this too : How to terminate a Process :

```
wmic process call terminate /?
```

So, you can give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
set "targetfile=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
set targetfile=%targetfile:\=\\%
@for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%# in ('wmic PROCESS CALL CREATE "%targetfile%" ^|findstr /I "ProcessId"') do set "PID=%%#"
echo The Process is created with PID=%PID%
pause
wmic process where ProcessId="%PID%" call terminate
REM Taskkill /PID %PID%
pause
```

---

And you can create a Subroutine named : `:Create_Process <TargetFile> <PID>` in order to call it like this :

```bat
@echo off
Title Start chrome process with a defined process ID
set "TargetFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Call :Create_Process "%TargetFile%" PID
echo The Process is created with PID=%PID%
pause
wmic process where ProcessId="%PID%" Call Terminate
REM Taskkill /PID %PID%
pause
Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------
:Create_Process <TargetFile> <PID>
Set "TargetFile=%~1"
Set TargetFile=%TargetFile:\=\\%
@for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%# in (
'wmic PROCESS CALL CREATE "%TargetFile%" ^|findstr /I "ProcessId"'
) do set "%2=%%#"
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------------------------
```